# Stacking images on Parallax effect

Tags: html, css

I am testing a parallax effect on a pagewide banner. I managed to get the effect working, however I would like to place on top of this banner a logo, thus an image. My HTML which I mocked up from various places around the internet looks like this:

> EDIT: Code removed in favor of CodePen link below

So far everything I have tried has not made me able to 'float' this logo over the existing pagewide banner. Am I having conflicting code or am I approaching this all wrong in the first place? Judging by my question you might notice I am a complete novice at this.

Please and thank you!

To further clarify my problem I have included a CodePen example of the problem I have as of right now. I would like to retain the subtle parallax effect and the navbar clipping to the top of the screen once you scroll past it. I have failed to do this so far:

> http://codepen.io/anon/pen/mdbGh

Pretend the image in the bottom left is the logo I want to 'float' over the banner.

Comment: Question updated with CodePen link.

Comment: You want to `position` the header, with the image `position: absolute` and a `z-index` greater than the elements you want the logo to display over.

Comment: Alright, that works but how do I make it so that the navbar clips to the bottom of the banner again?